# Remove code between special comments from file

Tags: regex, perl, bash, replace, sed

Let's say I have this code :

```
some code 1

// @if (debug)
code to remove
// @endif

some code 2

// @if (debug)
code to remove
// @endif

some code 2
```

I want to remove all the codes between `// @if (debug)` and `// @endif`. For this, I've found a `sed` command which works if there is only one instance of `// @if (debug)` but doesn't if there is several one, because `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matches (and so, in the example above, removes also `some code 2`). Here is the command:

```
sed -r -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\/\/\s*@if\s*\(\s*debug\s*\)([^\0]*?)\/\/\s*@endif//g;p;}' file_path.js > file_path.min.js
```

I've read that I could use `perl` which supports non-greedy matches but I wasn't able to make it works. Here is what a try:

```
perl -pe 's/\/\/\s*@if\s*\(\s*debug\s*\)([^\0]*?)\/\/\s*@endif//g' file_path.js > file_path.min.js
perl -0pe 's/\/\/\s*@if\s*\(\s*debug\s*\)([^\0]*?)\/\/\s*@endif//g' file_path.js > file_path.min.js
perl -0777 -pe 's/\/\/\s*@if\s*\(\s*debug\s*\)([^\0]*?)\/\/\s*@endif//g' file_path.js > file_path.min.js
```

Any idea on how I could make it works with `sed`, `perl` or any other tool like this ?

Comment: Oh the humanity of leaning toothpick syndrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^\/\/ @if (debug)/,/^\/\/ @endif/d' inputfile
some code 1


some code 2


some code 2
```

Comment: Wo it's working ! I wasn't aware of the existence of the d flag which is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A perl solution using the flip-flop operator:

```
perl -nle 'm{//\s*\@if\s*\(\s*debug\s*\)}..m{//\s*\@endif} or print' file_path.js
```

Remember to escape the `@`, otherwise `@if` and `@endif` are interpreted as array variables (`-w` will warn about it).

Comment: Also working but a bit more complex. Thanks for the working example and for pointing out my mistakes.